# Numpy: change max in each row to 1, all other numbers to 0

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement a numpy function that replaces the max in each row of a 2D array with 1, and all other numbers with zero:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1],
...               [2, 3],
...               [4, 5],
...               [6, 7],
...               [9, 8]])
>>> b = some_function(a)
>>> b
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

**What I've tried so far**

```
def some_function(x):
    a = np.zeros(x.shape)
    a[:,np.argmax(x, axis=1)] = 1
    return a

>>> b = some_function(a)
>>> b
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Method #1, tweaking yours:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [9, 8]])
>>> b = np.zeros_like(a)
>>> b[np.arange(len(a)), a.argmax(1)] = 1
>>> b
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

[Actually, `range` will work just fine; I wrote `arange` out of habit.]

Method #2, using `max` instead of `argmax` to handle the case where multiple elements reach the maximum value:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3]])
>>> (a == a.max(axis=1)[:,None]).astype(int)
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks much. Quick question on Method #1: why wouldn't my `:` slice syntax on the rows do the same thing as providing an array with the row indices themselves?

Comment: It seems that method #1 iterates over a just once, while method #2 iterates twice (in `max()` and in the `==`). Is this true?

Comment: Using `range` is actually 13% slower in my tests

Answer (score 7):

I prefer using numpy.where like so:

```
a[np.where(a==np.max(a))] = 1
```

Comment: I guess this iterates twice over a?

Comment: This leaves all other values unchanged; e.g. starting with [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], you end up with [1, 2, 3, 4, 1].

Answer (score 5):

`a==np.max(a)` will raise an error in the future, so here's a tweaked version that will continue to broadcast correctly.

I know this question is pretty ancient, but I think I have a decent solution that's a bit different from the other solutions.

```py
# get max by row and convert from (n, ) -> (n, 1) which will broadcast
row_maxes = a.max(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
np.where(a == row_maxes, 1, 0)
np.where(a == row_maxes).astype(int)
```

if the update needs to be in place, you can do

```py
a[:] = np.where(a == row_maxes, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Instead of `a.max(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)` you can do `a.max(axis=1, keepdim=True)`.

Comment: @a_guest Typo there. It's `keepdims`

Answer (score -1):

```
b = (a == np.max(a))
```

That worked for me