# keras backend proba to categorical

Tags: python, keras, backend

I am using keras backend to build a custom metric. The first step is to convert a proba tensor (output of softmax) to categorical data
e.g:

```
from keras import backend as K
y_pred = K.variable([[0.7, 0.2, 0.1],[0.2, 0.8, 0],[0.2,0.2,0.6],[0.9,0.05,0.05]])
K.eval(y_pred)
```

Gives

```
array([[ 0.69999999,  0.2       ,  0.1       ],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.80000001,  0.        ],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.2       ,  0.60000002],
       [ 0.89999998,  0.05      ,  0.05      ]], dtype=float32)
```

I would like to get:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0]], dtype=float32)
```

I found the K.argmax function but don't know how to use it to replace values in my tensor.

```
max_index = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, 1), "int32")
lol_index = K.arange(y_pred.shape[0], dtype="int32")
y_pred[index, max_index]
```

gives:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_32' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [4,3], [2,4], [2,4], [2].
```

Comment: Similar thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553722/restricting-the-output-values-of-layers-in-keras/44554112#44554112

Comment: This has been answered, albeit for a different problem, here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20295159/4895899

Comment: I am  talking about keras backend, it's not the same as numpy.

Comment: Does `K.round` work?

Comment: Yes it does but only for this special case. if you have 0.4, 0.4, 0.2 you will get 0 everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some research I found my solution:

```
K.one_hot(K.argmax(y_pred), 3)
```