# binary vector of max

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have a vector like

```
[2,5,8,1]
```

How can I turn that into a binary vector where all the elements are 0 except for the max element which will be represented as 1?

```
[0,0,1,0]
```

I'm hoping this can be elegantly done in **Tensorflow**.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295046/numpy-change-max-in-each-row-to-1-all-other-numbers-to-0

Comment: Thanks @JoeA, that looks like a numpy solution, I was hoping for a Tensorflow solution as I need it to be computed in the graph.

Comment: Ahhhh okay my apologies! I'm glad you got the answer though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
X = np.array([2,5,8,1])
one_hot = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.argmax(X), depth=tf.shape(X)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If all element equal to max value should be assigned `1` and the rest `0` you can do the following

```
[1 * (x == max(your_list)) for x in your_list]
```