# Convert the max of each row of numpy to 1 and other elements zero

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy array. I want to do the following to each row: convert the maximum of it to 1 and all other elements to zero. So, if I have:

```
first row: 10 8 0
second row: 1 2 3
third row: 5 3 6
```

Then, the first row becomes 1 0 0, 2nd row becomes, 0 0 1, and the last row becomes  0 0 1. I use

```
output=(input==np.max(input,axis=1))*1
```

But, it does not give me that. What is the easiest way to do this without using for loops?

Comment: Your approach is valid and works correctly with setting the `keepdims` parameter: `(a == np.max(a, 1, keepdims=True)) * 1`. Try to avoid shadowing built-in functions with variable names.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Interesting... I first thought the issue was that the np.max gives a row, while I need a column. So, I tried using reshape to make the max a column, but it didn't work. Howcome keepdims work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: change max in each row to 1, all other numbers to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295046/numpy-change-max-in-each-row-to-1-all-other-numbers-to-0) There you will find working solutions with reshaped row arrays.

Comment: As why it doesn't work without `keepdims`, read more on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).